# Angular 4: Apply styles in app from custom css from a json

Tags: angular

Problem is simple: Include style attributes as specified in the JSON (programmatically).

The json field is:

```
custom_css: "h1 { color:white; } #body-container.takeover .primary-color-bg{ background-color:#0092db; }"
```

I could think of one idea, custom variable for the 'styles' property of a component. Not working

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Service } from './services/json.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  styles: this.customStyles   // THIS
})
export class AppComponent {
  customStyles: Array<string> = [];

  constructor(private service: Service) {
    this.service.getJson().subscribe( (data: any) => {
      this.customStyles = data.custom_css;
    });
  }

}
```

Any idea how this could be done in Angular 4?

Comment: I see many questions about "how to load styles dynamically". What's the reason? Why don't you just write styles for every component?

Comment: All I can say is requirements vary. Sure I could have done that but thats not the case. In my case, the json has info about some channels, channels personalized by users. You need to retrieve info about how they have personalized their workspace in a channel. Long story but you get the main point.

Answer (score 1):

If you can rewrite your json:

```
custom_css:{ h1_color: "color:white",  bodyContainer_background:" color:#0092db"}
```

and

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Service } from './services/json.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
       <--------- Nothing here
})
export class AppComponent {
  customStyles: Array<string> = [];

  constructor(private service: Service) {
    this.service.getJson().subscribe( (data: any) => {
      this.customStyles = data.custom_css;
    });
  }

}
```

and in your html:

put `[ngStyle]="customStyles.h1_color"`

where you want to add the style.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did try some ideas inspired by you. I was unsuccessful. Will look further into this and post my results.